# Code to turn on/off flashlight but with screen lock?

Tags: android, flashlight

I am using this code to turn on flash light (in activity's onCreate method) and turn off (in activity's onStop method). Problem is when i press screen lock button my screen is turned off and locked and flash light also stopped (but my app is still running in background). How to keep flashlight on even if my app is minimized or screen is locked? 
I know its possible because there are some flash light apps on google playstore which keep flash light on even when minimized or screen locked.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Context c;
Camera cam;
Camera.Parameters p;

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    cam.stopPreview();
    cam.release();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    on();
}

public void on() {
    try {
        if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
            cam = Camera.open();
            p = cam.getParameters();
            p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            cam.setParameters(p);
            cam.startPreview();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: try to move your release code from onstop to ondestroy

Comment: Thanx man. Really helpful